# How to make an element fixed on top of the mobile keyboard?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, android-softkeyboard, uikeyboard

I am building an editor using editorJS. For PC, I created a sticky toolbar at the top which follows the viewport scroll. However, for mobile, the stikcy toolbar just won't get fixed on top of the viewport because of the damn virtual keyboard.

So I decided to remove the `position: sticky;` and apply `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` for mobile screen so that it sticks on top of the keyboard. I thought I would be able to calculate the right position for the toolbar in the `resize` and `scroll` event handlers. The procedures are as follows.

1. if `resize` happens, that means either the virtual keyboard is up/down or the browser header/footer is shown/disappeared by the scroll.
2. debounce the `resize` event so to store the `visualViewport.height` before the resize and after the `resize`.
3. when `resize` event ends, compare the the `visualViewport.height` before and after and set the difference as the `style.bottom` of the toolbar.
4. if `scroll` happens, `visibility: hidden;` the toolbar and calculate the position when the event ends. (also debouncing the `scroll` event)
5. `visiblity: visible` the toolbar to show it on top of the keyboard.

But, I was not able to achieve it because the [2] did not work. The resize event did not catch the `visualViewport.height` before the resize even with the debounce.

```
handleIOSKeyboardAppear(event) {
  if (!this.isMobileResizing) {
    console.log('start!', window.visualViewport?.height) <-- the same value
    this.isMobileResizing = true
  }

  console.log('resizing...')
  if (this.mobileResizeDebounceTimerId) {
    clearTimeout(this.mobileResizeDebounceTimerId)
  }

  this.mobileResizeDebounceTimerId = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('end!', window.visualViewport?.height)  <-- the same value
    this.isMobileResizing = false
  }, 500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution to this. Basically re-calculating the style.bottom every time the resize, scroll event happens.

the value of the style.bottom: `window.innerHeight - window.visualViewport.offsetTop - window.visualViewport.height`

```
// MARK: hang events on creation.
created() {
  if (this.isMobile) {
    window.visualViewport?.addEventListener('resize', this.handleIOSKeyboardAppear)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleMobileScroll)
  }
}

...

handleMobileScroll(event) {
  // MARK: hide the toolbar when scroll starts.
  if (!this.isMobileScrolling) {
    this.$refs.blockToolbar.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    this.isMobileScrolling = true
  }

  if (this.mobileScrollDebounceTimerId !== null) {
    clearTimeout(this.mobileScrollDebounceTimerId)
  }

  // MARK: if scroll ends, show the toolbar after 150ms.
  this.mobileScrollDebounceTimerId = setTimeout(() => {
    const toolbarBottomPosition =
      window.innerHeight -
      window.visualViewport?.offsetTop -
      window.visualViewport?.height
    const blockToolbar = this.$refs.blockToolbar
    blockToolbar.style.visibility = 'visible'
    blockToolbar.style.bottom = `${toolbarBottomPosition}px`
    this.isMobileScrolling = false
  }, 150)
},
handleIOSKeyboardAppear(event) {
  // MARK: hide the toolbar when mobile VisualViewport resize starts.
  if (!this.isMobileResizing) {
    this.$refs.blockToolbar.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    this.isMobileResizing = true
  }

  if (this.mobileResizeDebounceTimerId !== null) {
    clearTimeout(this.mobileResizeDebounceTimerId)
  }

  // MARK: if mobile VisualViewport resize ends, show the toolbar.
  this.mobileResizeDebounceTimerId = setTimeout(() => {
    const toolbarBottomPosition =
      window.innerHeight -
      window.visualViewport?.offsetTop -
      window.visualViewport?.height
    this.$refs.blockToolbar.style.bottom = `${toolbarBottomPosition}px`
    this.$refs.blockToolbar.style.visibility = 'visible'
    this.isMobileResizing = false
  }, 150)
},
```

Comment: However, I suggest utilizing the native feature to add anything on top of the keyboard because using JS to hang it there can't provide the smoothest experience to the user. You will need a lot more code to achieve that.